# Angular : My First Form - Property Name does not exist

Tags: angular

I am getting started with Angular Forms and the extremely steep associated learning curve.

Following along with this example for a reactive form [here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).

However when I try this locally I am getting the compile error:

```
Error: src/app/car-create-form/car-create-form.component.html:2:45 - error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'CarCreateFormComponent'.

2 <input id="name" type="text" [formControl]="name">
                                          ~~~~
src/app/car-create-form/car-create-form.component.ts:5:16
5   templateUrl: './car-create-form.component.html',
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component CarCreateFormComponent.
```

The declaration module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { CarCreateFormComponent } from './Car-create-form/Car-create-form.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CarCreateFormComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FontAwesomeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-car-create-form',
  templateUrl: './car-create-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./car-create-form.component.css']
})
export class CarCreateFormComponent {
name = new FormControl('');
}
```

And the html:

```
<label for="name">Name: </label>
<input id="name" type="text" [formControl]="name">
```

I have strictly followed the example - so what is wrong here?

Comment: Try renaming the name to something else like full_name.

Comment: Thanks but still have a compile error.

Comment: be sure you has imort the ReactiveFormsModule in the module where you declare the CarCreateFormComponent. If you declare in Main.module.ts, import in this module, if you declare the component in, e.g. Car.module.ts, import the ReactiveFormsModule in this module.

Comment: Have you tried to stop the Angular app (if it is running), rebuild and restart the app?

Comment: It looks like that was it. Thank you. So html hot reloads but clearly certain other actions require a restart?

Comment: try to use angular cli to generate your components/services/modules etc. Your component file name is not following conventions, thus you may encoutner issues soon or later. Also it's faster

Comment: Can you tell me what the file name should be?

Comment: You rwite: "It looks like that was it. Thank you. So html hot reloads but clearly certain other actions require a restart?". When you add a new Module in your module, sometimes you should "re-start" the server (same when you change the angular.json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML, you should use `formControlName="name"` for the input for connecting your control that you define in the `.ts` file to the HTML.